# Groovy script to call Python and batch file

Tags: groovy, jenkins-api, jenkins-email-ext, jenkins-groovy

I wish to send email containing build status of all child job.
Therefore, I have used batch and python script to prepare the html file, which I will be importing in Editable Email Notification plugin.

However, in Pre Send script tab, we can only write groovy script.
So I would like to call my python file, that contains my logic from groovy

Answer (score 0):

You would have to call your python script as part of the job (possibly via a shell action) and save the HTML in the workspace and the add that file to the email. Alternatively you could create a custom email template that does the same

Comment: I can't keep in shell as I need build status, which is only accessable in email plugin. Secondly, could you explain further on custom email